# Doctrine won't let me select specific fields

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

The symfony framework features an app/console file that can be executed via php to perform some maintenance tasks. It allows users to run DQL queries as well:

```
# php app/console doctrine:query:dql --hydrate=array \
    'SELECT u.id, u.nameFirst, u.nameLast  FROM DatabaseBundle:User u'  
array
  0 => 
    array
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'nameFirst' => string 'jaroslav' (length=8)
      'nameLast' => string 'rakhmatoullin' (length=13)
  1 => 
    array
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'nameFirst' => string 'Båb Kåre' (length=10)
      'nameLast' => string 'Ytrefoss' (length=8)
```

Observe that I selected three specific columns. The problem I'm having is that a similar query gives me an error when two tables are joined.

```
# php app/console doctrine:query:dql  --hydrate=array \
    'SELECT u.id , r FROM DatabaseBundle:User u JOIN u.roles r'

  [Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException]                   
  [Semantical Error] line 0, col -1 near 'SELECT u.id ,': 
     Error: Cannot select entity through identification variables 
     without choosing at least one root entity alias.
```

The following returns the whole user joined with his roles:

```
# php app/console doctrine:query:dql  --hydrate=array \
     'SELECT u, r FROM DatabaseBundle:User u JOIN u.roles r'
```

Obviously, I'm missing something.

Any ideas? I would appreciate links to appropriate docs too (on this specific matter).

Comment: I don't understand the error message very well, but I recall experiencing similar error messages, and solving my problem by selecting r.id, so I think you should try selecting more fields.

Comment: what about this? `'SELECT u.id , r.* FROM DatabaseBundle:User u JOIN u.roles r'`

Comment: greg0ire that's correct. i think you can't select a single field AND an "entity" object in a query like that.

Comment: @jere r.* seems to be equivalent to r (the ORM selects all fields anyway and db never sees 'r.*' -- according to docs, somewhere). The problem was resolved by explicitly selecting fields from the r alias as well: SELECT u.id , u.username , r.id, r.title FROM DatabaseBundle:User u JOIN u.roles r

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From the [documentation on "Partial Object Syntax"](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#partial-object-syntax):

> By default when you run a DQL query in Doctrine and select only a subset of the fields for a given entity, you do not receive objects back. Instead, you receive only arrays as a flat rectangular result set, similar to how you would if you were just using SQL directly and joining some data.
>
> If you want to select partial objects you can use the **partial** DQL keyword.
>
> ```
> php console doctrine:query:dql --hydrate array \
>   'SELECT partial s.{name ,id}, partial c.{name, id } 
>    FROM DatabaseBundle:ProductCategories c 
>    JOIN c.suppliers s ORDER BY s.name, c.name'
> ```

Comment: Note, you must include the primary key in a partial query - otherwise you get a nasty error.

Comment: Two years later I don't quite understand my own answer, but if I remember correctly, the key is that: every product category is mapped as "c" and every category.supplier[] is mapped as s. Every category has suppliers mapped through an "@annotated-join" in the ProductCategories class. Thanks for all the up-votes. I think 10 is enough.

Comment: But what if you really want to have the full object back? I mean for instance some fields of objects A and then the whole object B?

Comment: then you only add the table's alias without a dot in the select line :)