# How can I select specific Columns with createQueryBuilder in Doctrine ORM?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, query-builder

I'm using Doctrine `createQueryBuilder()` to construct queries in Symfony2. But, I don't want to take all columns in this entity. How can I select only the ID and Name?

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
        $query
            ->select('d')
            ->from('AcmeBundle:Demo', 'd')
            ->leftjoin('d.otherEntity', 'o');

        $query->setMaxResults(10);
        $results = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Thank you so much,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465353/doctrine-wont-let-me-select-specific-fields

Comment: Actually, the ORM is Doctrine2. Symfony is a web framework.

Answer (score 70):

Try following,

```
$fields = array('d.id', 'd.name', 'o.id');
//$fields = 'partial d.{id, name}, partial o.{id}';  //if you want to get entity object

$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$query
    ->select($fields)
    ->from('AcmeBundle:Demo', 'd')
    ->leftjoin('d.otherEntity', 'o');

$query->setMaxResults(10);
$results = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: will it hydrate query result ?

Comment: is there a way to set the fields from setParameter ?

Comment: `partial alias.{comma, fields}` is not working to me on symfony 2.4. Should it work or is it only for newer versions?

Comment: @hardik see "Hydration Modes" here https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#hydration-modes

Comment: @Vandervals Doctrine version 2.10 or greater. See https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.10/reference/partial-objects.html#partial-objects

Comment: I think it's also worth mentioning that it's required to include "_identifier/primary key column name_" in the columns list for all the entities (e.g., `id` for both `d` and `o` in `partial d.{id, name}, partial o.{id}`) while using the `partial` keyword to get the join's primary entity object (e.g.,`d`) instance mapped with the partial result set.

Comment: this solution does not work with **distinct**: `$qb->distinct('d.id, d.name')`. To make it work need to change it to this `$qb->select('DISTINCT d.id, d.name')`